# Can't compile the project after splitting the source files to cpp and h, getting "undefined refernce to..."

Tags: c++, inheritance, compilation, header

I had a project, where I had only `.cpp` files. It worked well, but then I realized, that it's not a good practice, so I decided to split it to `.cpp` and `.h` files. Nevetheless now I'm not able to compile the project. Could anybody please look at the source and tell me, where the problem is?

`Bot.h`

```
#ifndef BOT_H
#define BOT_H

#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;
/**
 * Class that represents casual Bot - the parent of other bots
 */
class Bot {
public:
    Bot();
    virtual ~Bot();
    bool initialized;
    string getRandomMessage();
    string getName();
protected:
    vector<string> messages;
    string name;
};

#endif  /* BOT_H */
```

`Bot.cpp`

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "Bot.h"

using namespace std;
string Bot::getRandomMessage() {
    int r = static_cast<double> (std::rand()) / RAND_MAX * this->messages.size();
    return messages[r];
}
Bot::Bot(){    
}
Bot::~Bot(){    
}
string Bot::getName() {
    return this->name;
}
```

Example of the class that inherits from the `Bot` class:

`GrumpyBot.h`

```
#ifndef GRUMPYBOT_H
#define GRUMPYBOT_H
#include "Bot.h"

class GrumpyBot : public Bot{
public:
    GrumpyBot();
    GrumpyBot(const GrumpyBot& orig);
    virtual ~GrumpyBot();
};

#endif  /* GRUMPYBOT_H */
```

`GrumpyBot.cpp`

```
#include "GrumpyBot.h"
GrumpyBot::GrumpyBot() {

    initialized = true;
    this->name = "GrumpyBot";
    messages.push_back("I hate dogs.");
    messages.push_back("I hate cats.");
    messages.push_back("I hate goats.");
    messages.push_back("I hate humans.");
    messages.push_back("I hate you.");
    messages.push_back("I hate school.");
    messages.push_back("I hate love.");
}
```

Till now it is ok, but problems appear in the `Server.cpp` class, where I try to create new instances of those classes and call their functions.
I include there both `#include "Bot.h"` & `#include "GrumpyBot.h"` and the compiler keeps getting me messages like `/home/ubuntu/NetBeansProjects/SemestralniPraceChat/./Server.cpp:335: undefined reference to 'GrumpyBot::GrumpyBot()'`

My makefile looks like this:

```
#macros
Remove=rm -rf
Doxygen=Doxyfile
RUN=./dvoram64
FLAGS=-Wall -pedantic -Wno-long-long -O0 -ggdb -lncurses -pthread -g
OBJECTS=main.o Bot.o Server.o Client.o

#generates final binary and documentation
all:    $(Doxygen)
    make compile

#build into final binary
compile: $(RUN)

#run program
run: $(RUN)
    $(RUN)


clean:
    $(Remove) dvoram64
    $(Remove) $(OBJECTS)

#generate documentation in '<login>/doc' folder
doc: $(Doxygen) /*
    ( cd ./ | doxygen $(Doxygen))

#rules how to compile into the executalble file
$(RUN): $(OBJECTS)

Bot.o: ./Bot.cpp ./Bot.h
    g++ $(FLAGS) -c ./Bot.cpp

DummyBot.o: ./DummyBot.cpp ./DummyBot.h ./Bot.h
    g++ $(FLAGS) -c ./DummyBot.cpp

GrumpyBot.o: ./GrumpyBot.cpp ./GrumpyBot.h ./Bot.h
    g++ $(FLAGS) -c ./GrumpyBot.cpp

JokerBot.o: ./JokerBot.cpp ./JokerBot.h ./Bot.h
    g++ $(FLAGS) -c ./JokerBot.cpp

WeatherBot.o: ./WeatherBot.cpp ./WeatherBot.h ./Bot.h
    g++ $(FLAGS) -c ./WeatherBot.cpp

Client.o: ./Client.cpp
    g++ $(FLAGS) -c ./Client.cpp

main.o: ./main.cpp ./Server.cpp ./Bot.h ./JokerBot.h ./WeatherBot.h ./GrumpyBot.h ./DummyBot.h ./Client.cpp
    g++ ./main.cpp $(FLAGS) -o ./dvoram64

Server.o: ./Server.cpp ./Bot.h ./JokerBot.h ./WeatherBot.h ./GrumpyBot.h ./DummyBot.h
    g++ $(FLAGS) -c ./Server.cpp
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

undefined reference is a linker error, you are not passing the objects for the linking process.

In the makefile, replace `main.o:` lines with

```
main.o: main.cpp 
     g++ $(FLAGS) -c main.cpp
```

remove `-lncurses` from `$(FLAGS)` and add:

```
link: <all the o files>
   g++ <all the o files> -lncurses -pthread -o dvoram64
```

then calling:

```
make link
```

will create the correctly linked executable.

Edit:

If you define the $(OBJECTS) variable, the link should be:

```
link: $(OBJECTS)
     g++ $(OBJECTS) -lncurses -pthread -o dvoram64
```

Comment: I tried to edit my `Makefile` according to your advice, but it didn't help at all... My current `Makefile` is here http://pastebin.com/LMv0tu0v and this is what I get when I'm trying to compile http://pastebin.com/AG9kieyW . Any idea, what I did wrong? :-/

Comment: Added to answer based on your current Makefile